# apche camel xml dsl get route definition is throwing an error with latest camel 3.19 version

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel

I have been looking for a while to resolve this on my own but ended up asking it here as I can't find any solution so far. We have a app developed on apache camel with xml dsl definition which is working fine in older version of apache camel. I updated it to latest version 3.19 and getting the following error during the deployment of the application.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 22; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'uri' is not allowed to appear in element 'get'.
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
      https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.18.0.xsd
       ">
       

    <camelContext
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <rest path="/say">
            <get uri="/hello">
                <to uri="direct:hello" />
            </get>
            <get uri="/bye" consumes="application/json">
                <to uri="direct:bye" />
            </get>
            <post uri="/bye">
                <to uri="mock:update" />
            </post>
        </rest>
        <route>
            <from uri="direct:hello" />
            <transform>
                <constant>Hello World</constant>
            </transform>
        </route>
        <route>
            <from uri="direct:bye" />
            <transform>
                <constant>Bye World</constant>
            </transform>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

The routes are defined as shown in the [official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: as far as I recall, uri has been replaced by path

Answer (score 1):

The `uri` attribute has been renamed to `path` since Camel version 3.16.0, see mention in this ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17673?focusedCommentId=17493997&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17493997

###### In camel versions before 3.16.0

see https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.15.0.xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="verbDefinition">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:optionalIdentifiedDefinition">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:param"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:responseMessage"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:security"/>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element ref="tns:to"/>
                    <xs:element ref="tns:toD"/>
                    <xs:element ref="tns:route"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="method" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        <![CDATA[ The HTTP verb such as GET, POST, DELETE, etc. ]]>
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="uri" type="xs:string"> <!-- ***** HERE ****** -->
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        <![CDATA[ Uri template of this REST service such as /{id}. ]]>
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
```

###### Since Camel v 3.16.0

see https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.16.0.xsd

```
<xs:complexType abstract="true" name="verbDefinition">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:optionalIdentifiedDefinition">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:param"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:responseMessage"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="tns:security"/>
                <xs:element ref="tns:to"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        <![CDATA[ The path mapping URIs of this REST operation such as /{id}. ]]>
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
```

Sadly, the Camel documentation has not been updated to reflect this change, the examples still use `uri` attribute: https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html#_rest_dsl_with_xml_dsl

Comment: reported https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-18694 to fix the documentation